# webpack-dev-server not creating dist folder on local

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

The webpack-dev-server is bundling the html, scss and js files successfully and the output is also getting served on `localhost:8080` but the dist folder is not getting created on local. Following is my webpack configuration:

```
var extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
   filename: 'main.css'
});

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      port: 3000
    },
    plugins: [
        extractPlugin,
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'public/index.html'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 8):

The webpack-dev-server serves the created bundle from memory and does not write it to the dist directory.

Comment: Is there a way to deal with that?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? If you just need the directory and bundle file created then just run webpack with out the dev server.

Comment: Makes complete sense. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--watch` to npm script solved the problem for me.

```js
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    ...
  }
}
```